# Principal components order - PCA in R

Tags: r, statistics, pca

I'm trying to do PCA in R with `principal`. Actually, I did but I'm curious why my principal compenents are not ordered numerically? I mean Why they are PC1, PC2, PC3. What's the point between this?

```
tb2 <- principal(tba, nfactors = 4)
tb2
Principal Components Analysis
Call: principal(r = tba, nfactors = 4)
Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
        PC2   PC3   PC1   PC4   h2     u2 com
bio1   0.89  0.28  0.32 -0.05 0.98 0.0248 1.5
bio2  -0.07 -0.22  0.09  0.96 0.99 0.0091 1.1
bio3   0.63  0.21 -0.22  0.60 0.85 0.1497 2.5
bio4  -0.60 -0.40  0.34  0.44 0.83 0.1682 3.3
bio5   0.78  0.15  0.46  0.33 0.95 0.0454 2.1
bio6   0.89  0.36  0.17 -0.21 0.99 0.0088 1.5
bio7  -0.50 -0.38  0.26  0.70 0.96 0.0395 2.8
bio8   0.85  0.12  0.20 -0.19 0.81 0.1896 1.3
bio9   0.85  0.24  0.41  0.03 0.95 0.0525 1.6
bio10  0.85  0.23  0.40  0.04 0.95 0.0533 1.6
bio11  0.90  0.34  0.21 -0.13 0.99 0.0058 1.4
bio12  0.16  0.94  0.03 -0.15 0.93 0.0743 1.1
bio13  0.29  0.93  0.18 -0.09 0.99 0.0086 1.3
bio14 -0.31 -0.18 -0.89 -0.05 0.92 0.0777 1.3
bio15  0.34  0.72  0.56 -0.02 0.94 0.0577 2.4
bio16  0.27  0.93  0.22 -0.10 0.99 0.0069 1.3
bio17 -0.17 -0.16 -0.93 -0.07 0.93 0.0725 1.1
bio18 -0.40 -0.29 -0.84 -0.06 0.96 0.0440 1.7
bio19  0.26  0.93  0.22 -0.09 0.99 0.0066 1.3

                       PC2  PC3  PC1  PC4
SS loadings           6.84 4.99 3.81 2.26
Proportion Var        0.36 0.26 0.20 0.12
Cumulative Var        0.36 0.62 0.82 0.94
Proportion Explained  0.38 0.28 0.21 0.13
Cumulative Proportion 0.38 0.66 0.87 1.00

Mean item complexity =  1.7
Test of the hypothesis that 4 components are sufficient.

The root mean square of the residuals (RMSR) is  0.03 
 with the empirical chi square  96803.04  with prob <  0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The order doesn't matter. If you're really concerned about it, you can rearrange them manually.

Comment: No it's not concerned me. I just wanted to learn is there anything important. If you say no it isn't important. Than no problem for me. Thanks!